# Deep Linking in iOS - Navigate to Apple Store if app not installed (Flutter)

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I followed the steps in this https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/set-up-universal-links to implement universal links and created a link that I published to the App Store. However, when I click on the deep link, I receive a 404 error in the browser saying the page can't be found.

When the app is installed, all the redirections with the deep link work correctly. My problem is navigating to the App Store to the app's page.

What should I check, and how can I determine if the problem is in the apple-app-site-association file or in some setting in the app?

I try to add * like prefix on url in app setting but this don't help.

Comment: A universal link wont take you to the App Store if the app isn't installed.  It just shows the page at the link. It sounds like you don't actually have a web page at the deep link location.  You can have a redirect at that page to the App Store.

Comment: A universal link is a URL that points to a resource that is "universal" on all platforms. I.e. in case the app is installed it deep links into the app, in case the app is not installed it links to a website that should show the same content for mobile web users. I guess what you want is an app-store redirect logic like this: https://github.com/danielgindi/app-redirect