What configuration to open App Store with Universal Link
I'm creating a Universal Link for my application.
We created a site in next js and configured the files correctly apple-app-site-association file: https://rune-links-webapp.vercel.app/.well-known/apple-app-site-association
I took inspiration from this service that opens the store correctly: https://h-art.dynalinks.app/.well-known/apple-app-site-association
I configure xcode on associated domains, and a link like https://rune-links-webapp.vercel.app/aaaa open my application. But if the application is not installed it doesn't work.
while with h-art.dynalinks.app/dl/665ec70949eae19a0e437087 open App Store
I check here https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/ and is correctly configured.
What configuration needs to be done to open the app store?
Thanks

A universal link won't open the App Store if the app isn't installed.  It just delivers the user to the URL in Safari.  On that page you need to implement appropriate logic to redirect to the app store/play store based on, say, the user agent.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78080325/deep-linking-in-ios-navigate-to-apple-store-if-app-not-installed-flutter and https://github.com/danielgindi/app-redirect
